# Python speed up document similarity calculation of corpus

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

My input is a string in this (spintax) format,

```
"The {PC|Personal Computer|Desktop} is in {good|great|fine|excellent} condition"
```

Then using itertools, I generate all possible combinations.
e.g.

```
"The PC is in good condition"
"The PC is in great condition"
.
.
.
"The Desktop is in excellent condition"
```

Out of these strings, I only want to keep the most unique ones based on a similarity threshold, for e.g. only keep strings having similarity of less than 60%. I used [SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) library but it is does not work well with large data sets (250K+ items) due to looping. Here is the current implementation,

```
def filter_descriptions(descriptions):
    MAX_SIMILAR_ALLOWED = 0.6  #40% unique and 60% similar
    i = 0
    while i < len(descriptions):
        print("Processing {}/{}...".format(i + 1, len(descriptions)))
        desc_to_evaluate = descriptions[i]
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(descriptions):
            similarity_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, desc_to_evaluate, descriptions[j]).ratio()
            if similarity_ratio > MAX_SIMILAR_ALLOWED:
                del descriptions[j]
            else:
                j += 1
        i += 1
    return descriptions
```

I am shortening the list (almost) every iteration, to speed up the process. But I definitely need a faster algorithm to tackle this. I tried Cosine Similarity too, but ran into scaling issues there. It worked ok for about 10K items, but above that it just stuck my machine.
Here's the implementation,

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(descriptions)
val = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[:10000], tfidf_matrix[:10000])
```

Any optimized solution for this? All I want is to pick n most unique strings from the list.

Comment: Not a solution, but I think that you have a bug there. You shouldn't increase j after deleting descriptions[j].

Comment: Updated the code, fixed that bug a few hours back :)

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do you begin all over again after finding a similar desc? Why not leave j as is after deleting descriptions[j]?

Comment: Fixed...thanks for identifying that, no wonder it was taking a lot of time :)

Comment: But I believe there's still a better approach out there...somewhere

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could be optimised is your use of `del`. Now you perform del a lot of times and altough I do not know how Python handles this, I think a solution using one del-statement is better, since I believe Python must create a new list for every del performed.

So I decided to test this approach:

```
import time
import argparse

def test1(long_list, max_num):
    """
    Removing values from a list with delete every step in the loop
    """
    i = 0
    while i < len(long_list):
        if long_list[i] > max_num:
            del long_list[i]
        else:
            i += 1
    return long_list


def test2(long_list, max_num):
    """
    Removing values from a list with delete, lastly after swapping values into the back of the array - marked as garbage
    """
    garbage_index = len(long_list) - 1
    i = 0
    while i <= garbage_index:
        if long_list[i] > max_num:
            long_list[i],long_list[garbage_index] =  long_list[garbage_index], long_list[i]
            garbage_index -= 1
        else:
            i += 1

    del long_list[garbage_index + 1 :]
    return long_list


def get_args():
    """
    Fetches needed arguments for test1() and test2()
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("list_size", help="Set the size of the list.", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("max_element", help="Set max-element value.", type=int)

    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Simply times the two test functions and prints the time difference
    """
    args = get_args()
    long_list = [x for x in range(args.list_size) ]
    print("Using list size {}".format(args.list_size))

    start = time.time()
    test1(long_list, args.max_element)
    end1 = time.time()
    test2(long_list, args.max_element)
    end2 = time.time()

    print("test1:",end1-start)
    print("test2:",end2-end1)
```

And got some interesting results for you:

```
$ python3 Code/Playground/stackoverflow/pyspeedup.py 10 5
Using list size 10
test1: 4.5299530029296875e-06
test2: 2.384185791015625e-06
$ python3 Code/Playground/stackoverflow/pyspeedup.py 100 50
Using list size 100
test1: 1.71661376953125e-05
test2: 5.9604644775390625e-06
$ python3 Code/Playground/stackoverflow/pyspeedup.py 1000 500
Using list size 1000
test1: 0.00022935867309570312
test2: 4.506111145019531e-05
$ python3 Code/Playground/stackoverflow/pyspeedup.py 10000 5000
Using list size 10000
test1: 0.006038665771484375
test2: 0.00046563148498535156
$ python3 Code/Playground/stackoverflow/pyspeedup.py 100000 5000
Using list size 100000
test1: 2.022616386413574
test2: 0.0004937648773193359
$ python3 Code/Playground/stackoverflow/pyspeedup.py 1000000 5000
Using list size 1000000
test1: 224.23923707008362
test2: 0.0005621910095214844
$ python3 Code/Playground/stackoverflow/pyspeedup.py 10000000 5000
Using list size 10000000
test1: 43293.87373256683
test2: 0.0005309581756591797
```

The test2() solution also doesn't create a new garbage list, but uses in memory swap within the same list - thus saving space and time.

Hope this helps towards a more optimized algorithm.